# Image now shown on react native android

Tags: react-native

I have an issue with Image on Android react-native
using like below but the image is not shown in the Android.

`<Image style={{ aspectRatio: 1, height: '100%', flex: 1 }} source={require('../../../assets/images/defaultBook.jpg')} />`

it's working totally fine in the IOS.
also if I change the source to URI it's working fine.
what is the problem with the Android Image?

react-natice version: 0.72.3

I'm using yarn workspace